# How to put the results of two queries in one table only?

Tags: sql

I have two queries that show different information grouped by Year and Month.

The first query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Videos_Finished, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM materials_students.finished_at) AS MONTH, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM materials_students.finished_at) AS YEAR
FROM materials_students
WHERE materials_students.finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH
```

The second query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Trails_Finished, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM components_students.finished_at) AS MONTH, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM components_students.finished_at) AS YEAR
FROM components_students
WHERE components_students.finished_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH
```

Now I want to put those information together in just one table like this:

```
Videos_Finished   Trails_Finished   Month   Year
-----------------------------------------------------
      123                11           1     2019
       99                 8           2     2019               
      156                14           3     2019

      etc
```

How can I do that ? In time. Both of those tables (`materials_student and components_students`) belong to the same database and at `materials_students` there is a `component_student_id` column which means I can join those two tables, but I do not know if it that helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data for all months of interest in both tables, just use `join`:

```
SELECT ms.year, ms.month, ms.Videos_Finished, cs.Trails_Finished
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as Videos_Finished, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ms.finished_at) AS MONTH, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ms.finished_at) AS YEAR
      FROM materials_students ms
      WHERE ms.finished_at IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
     ) ms JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as Trails_Finished, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cs.finished_at) AS MONTH, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cs.finished_at) AS YEAR
      FROM components_students cs
      WHERE cs.finished_at IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH
     ) cs 
     ON cs.YEAR = ms.YEAR and cs.MONTH = ms.MONTH     
ORDER BY cs.YEAR, cs.MONTH;
```

If some months can be missing from one or the other subquery, then you'll want an outer join instead.